# How to do Microsoft Graph API Filter on Lookup Column in SharePoint List Items?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, api, microsoft-graph

I am tried to apply Filter on Lookup column using Microsoft graph API filter. But it didn't filter. I have used below api to filter.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sites}/lists/{listname}/items?expand=fields(select=Id,Title,LookUpcolumn)&$filter=Fields/LookUpcolumn eq 'value'.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The the following expression demonstrates how to filter by *lookup* field id:

```
&filter=fields/<LookupFieldName>LookupId eq '<LookupFieldValue>'
```

> Pay attention to lookup field name format, in Microsoft Graph lookup
>   field value is exposed for Lookup Id by default

**Example**

Lets assume `Employee` list contains `Department` lookup field (refers to `Department` list), then the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/Employee/items?expand=fields(select=Id,Title,Department)&filter=fields/DepartmentLookupId eq '<deplookupId>'
```

will return list items filtered by `Department` lookup Id value

**Update**

It seems Graph API does not support to apply filter by *lookup value*

As a workaround you could consider the following solution to filter by lookup value (requires two requests).

Given the above example

1)first step would be to query `Departments` list by `Title` and return Id property (which corresponds to `DepartmentLookupId` property in `Employee` 
list):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/Department/items?expand=fields(select=Id)&filter=fields/Title eq '<value>'
```

2) and then to query `Employee` list by `Department` lookup Id:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/Employee/items?expand=fields(select=Id,Title,Department)&filter=fields/DepartmentLookupId eq '<deplookupId>'
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, You were right. But I want to filter with Text not a ID.

Comment: Bharat, indeed, the provided solution demonstrated how to filter by lookup id. The answer has been updated.

Comment: Don't forget to index the column you plan to use in filter.